# How to pass optional parameter that comes after another optional parameter that you don't wish to specify

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I want to pass a parameter to override a deafult parameter that comes later in the function declaration than another default parameter that I want to let be default. Is this possible? Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
function f(a:string, b:number=1, c:string='FOO'){
     // do stuff
}

f('val for a', 'val for c') // want b to still be default of 1
```

Answer (score 4):

According to documentation you need to explicitly set `b` to `undefined` to get the default.

```js
function test(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

test(undefined, 42, undefined);
```

Comment: sounds like it cannot be done and that I have to do this. Thanks. Solved

Answer (score 1):

You can use `undefined` to get the default working. Here's the way you can accomplish this thing in a good stylistic way

```
function test(a:string, b:number=1, c:string='FOO') {
    //other stuff
}

let _ = undefined

test('val for a', _, 'val for c');
```